# Is the given equation about tensor product correct?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Consider a second-order tensor $\mathbf{A}=A_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i\otimes \mathbf{e}_j$ and a scalar $t$. If $t$ can be given by $t=\mathbf{B}:\mathbf{C}$, where $\mathbf{B}=B_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i\otimes \mathbf{e}_j$ and $\mathbf{C}=C_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i\otimes \mathbf{e}_j$, respectively, then it seems that I can write
$$A_{ij}\cdot t=A_{ij}(B_{kl}C_{kl})=A_{ij}B_{kl}C_{kl}=D_{ijkl}C_{kl}, \tag{1}$$
where $\mathbb{D}=D_{ijkl}\mathbf{e}_i\otimes \mathbf{e}_j\otimes\mathbf{e}_k\otimes \mathbf{e}_l=\mathbf{A}\otimes\mathbf{B}$.

But is the operation in equation (1) correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (But just to make sure the dot in $A_{ij}\cdot t$ is NOT a scalar product, it is just $tA_{ij}$)

Comment: @ContraKinta Thank you. But I am still wondering how $t\mathbf{A}=tA_{ij}\mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_j$ become  $\mathbf{A}\otimes \mathbf{B}:\mathbf{C}$. Or in other words, is equation $$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{B}:\mathbf{C})=\mathbf{A}\otimes \mathbf{B}:\mathbf{C}$$ also correct in general?

Comment: Yes. (f by general you mean $\mathbf{B,C}$ are both rank 2 and therefore form a scalar upon double contraction, otherwise add another $\otimes$ between the tensors to indicate a new product)

Comment: And by "add another" I mean $\mathbf{A}\otimes(\mathbf{B}:\mathbf{C})=(\mathbf{A}\otimes\mathbf{B}):\mathbf{C}$